# can we append into existing file using sync() or syncFs() methods?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I made my own jar in hadoop and also own shell script shell script runs my jar

my hadoop jar working is, delete prev. dir if already exist because hadoop doesn't support APPEND and create new dir

but the problem is because of my service running continues every sec jar gets run and i can't see any dir on HDFS because jobs are running.

i just want to append my existing dir.

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem, but why not making your directory name unique, for example adding a unix timestamp in your directory every time you run your job?

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir, actually sir i want to develop Runtime mechanism .. my hadoop jar is Log Analyzer jar so the thing is as soon as the log gets generated i have to map them , reduce them so i have to see my logs runtime but the problem is i cant append into existing files in hadoop